Deriving $k_i$ for $\hat{\beta} = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i y_i$ where $\hat{\beta}$ is the OLS -estimator
This question relates to this post: Prove that the OLS estimator of the intercept is BLUE
Since I can't yet directly comment under the original post so I post my question here.
In the original post the regression model is defined as $y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + u_i$ and the OLS-estimator for $\beta$ is naturally denoted as $\hat{\beta}$.
Then $\hat{\beta}$ is further defined as a linear combination in the form $\hat{\beta} = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i y_i$ where $k_i = \frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$.
I assume $\hat{\beta}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$ and I wonder how $k_i$ is derived from the said linear combination as it is.

The answer is embedded in @Ben's answer to the linked question, where the BLUE nature of the OLS estimator is derived.

If you are asking how to find a formula for $k_i$ given the formula for $\hat\beta,$ note that $k_i$ is the derivative of $\hat\beta$ with respect to $y_i.$  If that's not your question, could you clarify what the question is?

@whuber Hi, my question pertains the post I link to. The author in that post referred to the $k_i$ whose form I wasn't able to derive myself first. Hence this post.

Using the vector approach in the linked question and answer, we can derive a general result for multiple linear regression and then derive the special case of interest for simple linear regression.  You can write the OLS estimator as the linear function:
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\text{OLS} 
= (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{y}.$$
Setting $\mathbf{k} \equiv [\mathbf{x} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1}]$ to be the $n \times p$ matrix of coefficients of this linear function of $\mathbf{y}$ (with $p$ being the number of regression coeffcients being estimated), we get:
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\text{OLS} 
= \mathbf{k}^\text{T} \mathbf{y} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n k_{i,1} y_i \\[6pt]
\sum_{i=1}^n k_{i,2} y_i \\[6pt]
\vdots \\[6pt]
\sum_{i=1}^n k_{i,p} y_i \\[6pt]
\end{bmatrix}.$$
If we let $\mathbf{H} \equiv (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1}$ denote the $p \times p$ inverse-Gramian matrix for the regression then we can write the linear coefficients in the general form:
$$k_{i,j} 
= [\mathbf{x} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1}]_{i,j} 
= [\mathbf{x} \mathbf{H}]_{i,j} 
= \sum_{\ell = 1}^p x_{i,\ell} H_{\ell,j}.$$
These coefficients require computation of the inverse-Gramian matrix for the regression, and the form of this matrix depends on the number of coefficients $p$ in the regression equation.  The formula can be reduced for some special cases for low $p$, including the case of simple linear regression.

Simple linear regression: Your problem concerns the case with $p=2$ coefficients (simple linear regression) with design matrix of the form:
$$\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 \\
1 & x_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
This design matrix gives the Gramian and inverse-Gramian matrices:
$$(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}
n & \sum x_i \\[6pt]
\sum x_i & \sum x_i^2 \\[6pt]
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \quad \quad 
\mathbf{H} = (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} = \frac{1}{n \sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum x_i^2 & -\sum x_i \\[6pt]
-\sum x_i & n \\[6pt]
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Your concern is the linear coefficients for the estimator for the slope coefficient, which is the second regression parameter.  For this parameter, the linear coefficients are:
$$\begin{align}
k_{i,2} 
&= \sum_{\ell = 1}^2 x_{i,\ell} H_{\ell,2} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{-\sum x_i + n x_i}{n \sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{x_i - \bar{x}_n}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x}_n)^2}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

I am not going to engage in vectorial arguments for they are already stated in other answers and primarily due to the fact that what OP asked warrants a simpler treatment.
C&B offers a particularly ingenuous and elegant way to handle this in an elementary manner, the meat of which is in the following general result:
Result $1:$ Let $\boldsymbol v$ be an arbitrary vector of constants and let $\boldsymbol c$ be a vector of positive constants. Define $\mathcal A:=\{\boldsymbol a\mid \sum a_i =0\}.$ If $\bar v_c$ is the weighted mean of the elements of $\boldsymbol v$ with weights corresponding to the elements of $\boldsymbol c, $ then $$\sup_{\boldsymbol a\in\mathcal A}\left\{\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i\right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{ a_i^2}{c_i}}\right\}= \sum_{i=1}^k c_i(v_i-\bar v_c) ^2.\tag 1\label 1$$ The supremum is attainable at any $\boldsymbol a$ where $a_i:= Kc_i(v_i-\bar v_c), ~~K\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}.$
Coming specifically to the problem, any linear estimator would be of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n d_iY_i.$ Unbiasedness of the estimator would constrain $\boldsymbol d$ such that $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n d_i&=0,\\ \sum_{i=1}^n d_ix_i&= 1.\end{align}\tag 2\label 2$$
To obtain BLUE of $\beta, ~\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2$ needs to be minimized. Here, Result $1$ would be used: take $k=n, ~v_i=x_i, ~c_i=1, ~a_i=d_i.$ This means $\bar v_c=\bar x. $ If $d_i:= K(x_i-\bar x), $ then such $\boldsymbol d$ would maximize $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n d_ix_i\right) ^2/\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2$ among all $\boldsymbol d$s satisfying $\eqref 2.$
Again by $\eqref 2,~1=\sum_{i=1}^n d_ix_i= K\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x) x_i= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2\implies K=1/\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2.$ Then one concludes $$d_i= \frac{(x_i-\bar x) }{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2},~i=\{1,\ldots,n\}\tag 3\label 3.$$

Appendix
Proof of Result $1:$ The proof is based on Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.
Consider a collection $\mathcal B:=\left\{\boldsymbol b\mid \sum b_i=0\wedge \sum b_i^2/c_i=1\right\}.$ For any $\boldsymbol a\in\mathcal A, $ take $\boldsymbol b\in \mathcal B$ with $b_i:= \frac{a_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^2/c_i}}.$ What is to be maximized is $\left(\sum_{i=1}^k b_iv_i\right) ^2.$
Define $C:=\sum c_i.$ Now consider two random variables $B, V$ such that $$\Pr\left(B=\frac{b_i}{c_i}, V=v_i\right) =\frac{c_i}C, ~~i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}.$$ It is easy to note that $\mathbf EB=0, ~\mathbf EV=\bar v_c.$ Then \begin{align}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{b_i}{c_i}\right)(v_i)\left(\frac{c_i}C\right)\right\}^2&=(\operatorname{Cov}(B,V))^2\\&\leq (\operatorname{Var} B) (\operatorname{Var} V) \\&\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{b_i}{c_i}\right)^2\left(\frac{c_i}C\right)\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^k (v_i-\bar v_c) ^2\left(\frac{c_i}C\right)\right)\tag 4\label 4;\end{align} using $\sum b_i^2/c_i=1$ in $\eqref 4,$ it can be concluded that the RHS of $\eqref 1$ acts as an upper bound. Finally for the specific choice of $a_i, $ the attainment can be deduced.
$\blacksquare$
--
Reference:
$\rm[I]$ Statistical Inference, George Casella, Roger L. Berger, Wadsworth, $2002, $ sec. $11.2.4, 11.3.2.$

Thank you all for the answers!
I've come up with a derivation in scalar form after many trials and errors and decide to post my own attempt here.
Now that I'm not entirely sure of my solution and I'm aware this is not a rigorous proof so I present a detailed calculation.
Please correct me if you spot any mishap in my line of reasoning!
$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} = \hat{\beta}$$
We expand this expression
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$
$$ = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n [y_i (x_i - \bar{x})-\bar{y}(x_i - \bar{x})]}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$
$$ = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i (x_i - \bar{x})-\bar{y}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$
$$ = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i (x_i - \bar{x})-\bar{y}\cdot 0}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i (x_i - \bar{x})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$
And finally, this equality holds
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i (x_i - \bar{x})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i y_i $$
on the condition that:
$$if \ k_i = \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$

If that was the question, it readily follows by expanding the numerator as you did here. This doesn't necessarily mean it is BLUE. You have to show that, as the other answers deduced. If that was the only question, your answer is the correct one otherwise if you wanted to see the $k_i$ for BLUE, you have to follow either of the approaches detailed in the other answers.
